# How to get the values of an element by name

Tags: t-sql, xpath

I am using T-SQl and xPath to query an xml doc. and I need to extract the value of an element by name

This is the way I initially implemented the code "using element indexing to access the element" but since element  can have multiples element of  , it does not longer work properly.
 n.value(''./ROLES[1]/ROLE[1]/BORROWER[1]/GOVERNMENT_MONITORING[1]/HMDA_RACES[1][./HMDA_RACE/EXTENSION/ULDD:OTHER/ULDD:HMDA_RACE_EXTENSION/ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DETAIL/ULDD:HMDARaceType][1]'',''VARCHAR(100)'')

This is the xml I am querying

```
<HMDA_RACES>
                                                <HMDA_RACE>
                                                    <EXTENSION>
                                                        <ULDD:OTHER xmlns:ULDD="http://www.datamodelextension.org/Schema/ULDD">
                                                            <ULDD:HMDA_RACE_EXTENSION>
                                                                <ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DESIGNATIONS>
                                                                    <ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DESIGNATION>
                                                                        <ULDD:HMDARaceDesignationType>Samoan</ULDD:HMDARaceDesignationType>
                                                                    </ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DESIGNATION>
                                                                </ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DESIGNATIONS>
                                                                <ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DETAIL>
                                                                    <ULDD:HMDARaceType>NativeHawaiianOrOtherPacificIslander</ULDD:HMDARaceType>
                                                                </ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DETAIL>
                                                            </ULDD:HMDA_RACE_EXTENSION>
                                                        </ULDD:OTHER>
                                                    </EXTENSION>
                                                </HMDA_RACE>
                                                <HMDA_RACE>
                                                    <EXTENSION>
                                                        <ULDD:OTHER xmlns:ULDD="http://www.datamodelextension.org/Schema/ULDD">
                                                            <ULDD:HMDA_RACE_EXTENSION>
                                                                <ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DETAIL>
                                                                    <ULDD:HMDARaceType>White</ULDD:HMDARaceType>
                                                                </ULDD:HMDA_RACE_DETAIL>
                                                            </ULDD:HMDA_RACE_EXTENSION>
                                                        </ULDD:OTHER>
                                                    </EXTENSION>
                                                </HMDA_RACE>
                                            </HMDA_RACES>
```

this is what I am trying but I am not getting the result I want.

```
value(''./ROLES[1]/ROLE[1]/BORROWER[1]/GOVERNMENT_MONITORING[1]/HMDA_RACES[child = "ULDD:HMDARaceType"][1]'',''VARCHAR(100)'')
```

a successful query would return value "NativeHawaiianOrOtherPacificIslander White". I am getting just the first value "NativeHawaiianOrOtherPacificIslander"

Answer (score 0):

Just in terms of the xpath expression, and using the xml code in your question, this expression

```
*//HMDARaceType/text()
```

or this:

```
//*[local-name()='HMDARaceType']/text()
```

selects

```
    NativeHawaiianOrOtherPacificIslander
    White
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: no, I get back an error saying "requires a singleton (or empty sequence)".
you're correct, I need to get the values " NativeHawaiianOrOtherPacificIslanderWhite".
Basically, I need the values of each ULDD:HMDARaceType element

Comment: @y-user I guess it depends on your implementation. I changed the answer to account for `local_name()`. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: I am using this but, still does not work
n.value(''./ROLES[1]/ROLE[1]/BORROWER[1]/GOVERNMENT_MONITORING[1]/HMDA_RACES[1]/HMDA_RACE[local-name()="ULDD:HMDARaceType"][1]'',''VARCHAR(100)'')
if I use //*element, it gives me an error

Comment: @y-user - then I'm afraid I can't help you beyond this. As I said, the xpath expression, on its own (with or without the `local_name()`) was tested on a couple of xpath test pages and it works. So the problem must have something to do with T-SQL.